# Facebook: Get public photos from user ID

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the public photos of a given user by his facebook ID. That users are previous registed in my Android app. I am trying to do this with my access token (given on my login in my app) but this give me an error of permissions. Do you have any suggest?

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields","user_photos");
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/" + "USER_ID" + "/photos",
            parameters,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    //Response of photos
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`user_photos` is a permission, not a field. You have to authorize the user with the `user_photos` permission in order to get his photos. You may not have done that, that´s why you get a permission error. It would be good to know the exact error message though.

Anyway, this should be correct:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me/photos",
        parameters,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                //Response of photos
            }
        }
);
```

Use `/me` instead of the User-ID, the Access Token is bound to one specific user anyway.

What fields you can use is explained in the API reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/photo

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the *"fields"* key with *"scope"*.

```
parameters.putString("scope","user_photos");
```

Also, this might be the case with latest Facebook Privacy Policy updates.
Had a similar problem myself.

Comment: sorry, but that´s a graph request, not login. login: scope parameter. graph request: fields parameter. make sure you know when to use which one and why.